# После установки через андроид студио Две иконки на рабочем столе

Tags: java, android

Получается сделал 2 Активити, как я понял у меня и две иконки.
Можно ли сделать два Активити но с одной иконкой.
В процессе пользуюсь первой Активити,после клип на Баттон вызываю второй Активити, но не наоборот.

Comment: количество иконок от количества активностей не зависит. Скорее всего у вас в манифесте прописано и `android:icon`, и `android:roundIcon` и устройство с высоким API. Или что-то такое.

Comment: Может в приложениях, а не на рабочем столе? Тогда в манифесте в тэге второй активности уберите этот фильтр         
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`